Movie with madman warden and killer friend
Plot: 
A gang of young people secretly enter (on a bet) a sort of hypermarket. There's a warden, who wears BDSM clothes and is an ex-convict.
One by one, the youths are killed by an unknown man and they think the warden is the killer inside. When the warden finds them, they beat him and try to escape to call the police but another killer comes out and, before he kills another one of the youths, the warden discovers him. It is his gay lover, and an ex-inmate.
The warden beats the killer but the killer wounds him in the neck with a big knife.
The police arrive and the warden, right before he dies, tells the truth to agents and to the chief of the hypermarket: "The killer was my friend, he went mad in prison. When others tried to beat him, I defended him."
The movie ends with the real killer smiling while is driving a truck.
Someone know the title?
Other Info:
Release year: 1988-93
Format: VHS
Country: USA
Other info: B-movie, there is a similar movie with only one killer and this time is the real killer,the killer has the eyes painted black or white(i'm not sure)

Reminiscent of Intruder from 1989, but some of the details don't fit. (Maybe it's just that similar movie you mentioned?)

No,is different movie,without Sam Raimi

Maybe you could clarify a few things: 1. By 'hypermarket' do you mean a supermarket? A mall? What did it look like or contain? 2. By 'warden' do you mean a security guard? Something else? 3. "killer has the eyes painted black or white" Is that the killer in the movie you're looking for, or in that other, similar movie?

I don't know how to tell in english..a big market,warden I meant security guard,killer painted in the movie which i looking for

You're looking for Hide and Go Shriek (AKA Close Your Eyes and Pray) from 1988.

A group of teens decide to spend a night at a furniture store the father of one of them owns. A homeless ex-con security guard is staying the night too. During the night, someone with a taste for cross-dressing breaks in and begins to pick off the teens during a game of hide and seek.

You described it well. The killer turns out to be Zack, Fred's gay lover from prison, and he attacks Fred. In the end, Fred manages to tell the police about Zack before succumbing to his wounds and dying. Zack, presumed to be dead after falling down an elevator shaft, is then seen driving an ambulance, smiling at the camera. The movie is currently available on Youtube. Here's the trailer:



